# How to mirror flip animation curves in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a animation that moves my camera from **left to right**. Now I'd like to copy it with 'mirror' transformation so I can use it to move from **right to left**.

Is it possible to do it using script or purely in editor?

Answer (score 3):

go to your animation clip and check the mirror box
 [image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it in few hours.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work for me (2D). Here are some explanations: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mirror-animation-clip-through-script.222217/